# Tailwind CSS renders locally but not on GitHub pages

Tags: github-pages, tailwind-css

I've got TailwindCSS working locally but it's not working on GitHub pages. I'm very new to all of this so I'm unsure where to even look.

Comment: The reason is that you dont include the tailwind styles in your head.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You're talking to a Tailwind noob here.

Comment: @pirus92 I add a answear for more readablity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one style in your head area in your DOM.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">`

But this is not the style you have built locally. This means you have to add the generated style from your local environment into your HTML head area.

I thing that is your style file what you need: `https://github.com/syueyan/syueyan.github.io/blob/main/dist/assets/index.eb05b1e4.css`

Comment: @prius92 no, like this :-) `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yueyan.dev/assets/index.eb05b1e4.css" />`

Comment: @pirus yes because you dont have this file on your server. take this link: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yueyan.dev/dist/assets/index.eb05b1e4.css" />`